# Refactor variable names in JavaScript code

Tags: code-golf, javascript

Your challenge today is to refactor JavaScript code. You will take three strings as input; a JavaScript string, a old variable name, and the name you want to refactor it to. For example, an input of

```
"var x = 100; alert(x);", "x", "num"
```

Will output

```
"var num = 100; alert(num);"
```

---

Here's a more advanced test case:

```
"var gb = 1; var g = bg = 2; gb = bg = g = function(gg) { alert(gb); };
var str = 'g gb bg gg'; var regexp = /gb gb gb/g; //comment gb gb g g
/*gb gb g g*/", "gb", "aaa"
```

It should output

```
var aaa = 1; var g = bg = 2; aaa = bg = g = function(gg) { alert(aaa); };
var str = 'g gb bg gg'; var regexp = /gb gb g g/g; //comment gb gb g g
/*gb gb g g*/
```

And the same JS input with the other arguments `"g", "aaa"` should output

```
var gb = 1; var aaa = bg = 2; gb = bg = aaa = function(gg) { alert(gb); };
var str = 'g gb bg gg'; var regexp = /gb gb gb/g; //comment gb gb g g
/*gb gb g g*/
```

---

Here is one last much more complicated test case:

```
var g = 1; "g\"g"; "g'"; g; '"g\'g"g'; /g"\/*\//g; g; "// /*"; g; "*/"
```

It should output, with other parameters `"g"` and `"a"`, this:

```
var a = 1; "g\"g"; "g'"; a; '"g\'g"g'; /g"\/*\//g; a; "// /*"; a; "*/"
```

(sidenote: I really like `/g"\/*\//g`; I think that's just evil `:D`)

---

Full specification:

- For simplicity, you may ignore scope. Ex. `"var a=1; function(){var a=2;}; var o={a: 3}", "a", "b"` can output `var b=1; function(){var b=2;}; var o={b: 3}`.
- Text in strings (`'...' and "..."`), regexps and their modifiers (`/.../...`), and comments (`//...\n` and `/*...*/`) must not be modified.
- Also for simplicity, a valid identifier is one that starts with a letter, dollar sign, or underscore, and the rest of the characters are letters, numbers, dollar signs, or underscores.
- You may assume that the input contains no syntax errors.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes will win.
- If you use network access, all bytes downloaded from the network count towards your score.
- You must use an actual programming language. No IDE solutions, like emacs or vim keystrokes. ;)

Comment: wait, what's wrong with vim keystrokes? :-)

Comment: do we have to support `/[/]/` (character classes containing unescaped slash characters)? Ruby doesn't.

Comment: Asking the same as @JanDvorak above: do we need to support /[/]/ (character classes containing unescaped slash characters)? Most languages with built-in support for regular expressions don't; however, JavaScript does.

Comment: @toothbrush No, you do not. (Sorry for forgetting to reply ;-))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Ruby, 134 (113?) characters

```
*c,o,n=*$<;puts (c*?\n).gsub(/('|")((\\?+.)*?)\1|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|\/\/.*|\/(\[\g<2>\]|\g<2>)+?\/\w*|([\w$]+)/){$5==o.chop&&n.chop||$&}
```

Unicode is not supported. If Unicode identifiers are to be supported, replace `\w` with `[[:word:]]`  and `[\w$]` with `([[:word:]]|\$)` (and adjust the backreferences).

If unescaped slashes inside regexp literals (such as `/[/]/`) don't need to be supported, we can handle them together with string literals (**116 characters**). This also gives us string flags:

```
*c,o,n=*$<;puts (c*?\n).gsub(/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|\/\/.*|('|"|\/)((\\?+.)*?)\1\w*|([\w$]+)/){$4==o.chop&&n.chop||$&}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
*code, old, new = *$<

puts code.join("\n").gsub (/
     ('|")((\\?+.)*?)\1           #strings
   | \/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/             #multiline comments
   | \/\/.*                       #single-line comments
   | \/(\[\g<2>\]|\g<2>)+?\/\w*   #regexes
   | ([\w$]+)                     #identifiers and keywords
/x){
  if $5 == old.chop then new.chop else $& end
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 122

```
@a=<>;chomp(($y,$x)=(pop@a,pop@a));$_=join'',@a;s!//.*?\n|/\*.*?\*/|("|'|/)(\\?+.)*?\1\w*|([\w\$]+)!$3eq$x?$y:$&!sge;print
```

i.e. (semi-ungolfed)

```
@a=<>;
chomp(($y,$x)=(pop@a,pop@a));
$_=join'',@a;
s!//.*?\n|/\*.*?\*/|("|'|/)(\\?+.)*?\1\w*|([\w\$]+)!$3eq$x?$y:$&!sge;
print
```

practically the same as Ruby's short version answer (except I didn't knew about possessive quantifiers trick and my first take was slightly longer). Regexp is shorter, but 'I/O' part spoils everything (Perl can't do `(@a,$x,$y)=<>`), and my assumption (the same I see in Ruby's, if I'm not mistaken) was we feed JS string line by line through STDIN, followed by 'old name' and 'new name' on separate lines.

Answer (score 1):

## ECMAScript 6, 136 bytes

```
(s,o,n)=>s.replace(/\/\/.*?\n|\/\*[\s\S]+?\*\/|('|")(\\\1|[^\1])+?\1|\/(\\u[a-f\d]{4}|\\.|[^\/])+\/[angi]*|[a-z_$][\w$]*/gi,x=>x==o?n:x)
```

*Runs fine on any recent version of Firefox/Google Chrome.*

---

It creates a function with three parameters:

1. The code
2. The old variable name
3. The new variable name

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A6zM7/3/) for an example.