# Golf my variables (and code)!

Tags: code-golf, javascript

Specifically, this references JavaScript, a programming language that happens to be one you can run on StackExchange/StackOverflow. However, you may use any programming language to do this challenge. **This is not actual JS golfing, but merely a "code-golfable" challenge. Actual complete parsing of JS is not needed.**

An example of JS looks like this (try running all the snippets in here):

```js
const constant = 1
var value = 2
for (let i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
    value += constant + value // Addition
}
// Print the value
document.write(value)
```

Problem is, I want my code size to be a bit smaller. So, I could rename the variables to make it look like this:

```js
var a = 1
var b = 2
for (let i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
    b += a + b // Addition
}
// Print the value
document.write(b)
```

Notice how the variables have been changed to one letter, and the `const` keyword has been shortened to `var`. Then, we can remove most spaces and all comments:

```js
var a=1
var b=2
for (let i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
b+=a+b
}
document.write(b)
```

(Again, this is not "complete" compression, and is just a challenge.)

So, here are the rules (look at the test case; it will make more sense):

- The keywords `const` , `let` , `var` , `while`, and `for` are not variables (notice the spaces!) and should not be changed, with the exception of `const` , which should be changed to `var`  for shortening.
- A variable is defined as the longest string of characters that contain only the characters `0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_$`, not including the rule above. Furthermore, a variable is a variable if and only if one variable is preceded with `const` , `let` , or `var`  (with spaces).
- All variables with the same name must be renamed into a single character variable (one of `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_$`). All variables with different names must have different values in the result. You may assume that there are no more than 50 unique variables, so only one character is required.
- A single-line comment is all the characters at or after `//`
- All single-line comments should be removed.
- All spaces that are not within keywords must be removed. (Not newlines!)
- **After all of this,** remove any empty lines. This includes comment removal.
- Compact numbers! If a number is an integer, it is defined a number, but with a `.` and all zeros at the end.
- If an integer has more than two zeros, write the number before the final zeros (before the dot), an `e`, then the number of zeros (`30000` to `3e4`, `1515000` to `1515e3`). This is optional for two zeros. While this is not complete, it would be too complicated to compact numbers well.
- You should output all other characters normally.

There is only one test case, but it is a strange one!

### Test case:

```js
// Hello world, but stranger!

   // funny spacing

const m = 72000.00 / 1000
var h = String.fromCharCode(m)
  let string = " world!" // Value to print
 
 var l
for (let i = 1.00000; i < string.length; i++) {
// Number prototype to throw off some lazy variable detection
Number
      console.log(string[i]) // Print each value
   l += string[i]
}
string = string.split("").join("<br>")
 h = l.toUpperCase()

document.write("<!DOCTYPE html><i>" + h.toUpperCase() + "    " + string + "</i>")
```

### Result:

```js
var m=72e3/1e3
var h=String.fromCharCode(m)
let s=" world!"
var l
for(let i=1;i<s.length;i++){
Number
console.log(s[i])
l+=s[i]
}
s=s.split("").join("<br>")
h=l.toUpperCase()
document.write("<!DOCTYPE html><i>"+h.toUpperCase()+"    "+s+"</i>")
```

Notice `Number`! This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Surely the single character variable shouldn't be one of `0123456789`? And would it be a valid assumption that all long variable names don't start with a digit?

Comment: So should `const` change to `var` or not? (first rule says no, first example says yes)

Comment: Shouldn't `unicodeH` and `string` change to a single character variable name? Also, in the for loop, couldn't the spaces on thate line be removed?

Comment: Why isn't `for (let i = 0; i < 21; i++) {` in the final iteration of the example `for(let i=0;i<21;i++){` (spaces removed, except after `let `)?

Comment: Sorry for all those problems, just saw the comments! Thanks for the help.

Comment: doesn't this question essentially require you to parse the entire JS grammar? Seems a bit broad

Comment: If `const` is embedded in a function name or method, should it be replaced by `var`? Example `h=l.isconst()` -> `h=l.isvar()`. I assume this isn't acceptable, but the only current answer fails this test. And while it might not be found in actul JS (disclaimer: I don't know JS) this test case should probably still be included

Comment: Your last test case seems to contradict "_All spaces that are not within keywords must be removed._", since the spaces within strings are kept as is.. Also, if you have a variable `div` and an html-tag `<div>`, your current rules would indicate both are getting replaced with a single character, instead of just the variable. (And just like in your example, you forgot to remove the space at `for (` in your final test case.)

Comment: I fixed the space after `for `, somehow didn't catch that! Anyway, that is a good point, @jezza_99, but usually variables are declared with a space after them, so it would be `h=l.isconst ()` which doesn't really seem likely. I don't want to make this question overcomplicated, so I'll stick with the current rules.

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/20066/108687)

Comment: @Jacob I deleted the notice about the differences between the two; didn't realize that someone would say that! 1) We refactor multiple names, 2) The names are preset and shortened, and 3) This is compression, so it has a lot more things!

Comment: @Infigon Oh, this isn't a duplicate, and is in fact quite an interesting and different challenge. It's just related, thought I'd send the link if anyone was interested in a similar challenge

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>137</s> 134 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
¶¡ε„//¡нðÚð¡εD'¬¿Qi'¢Ž}.γžj'$«©så}}˜Ćü2εнð«D„¢Ž†³#ð«Qàiyθˆë¨}D¯ÙskDdi®èë\]JõK».γ'.Qyd~}εDdiÐïQiï}D'.å≠iγ`D¨_ig'es}J]JDI‚ε'"¡ιθ€…"ÿ"}`:
```

I/O as a multi-line string.

Some minor notes:

1. The space at `for (` is removed as well, unlike the test cases.
2. Variables that are already a single letter (e.g. `i`) are still counted as any other variable, and therefore replaced with another letter in alphabetical order.
3. Assumes the input JavaScript snippet will never start with a double quote `"`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##VVFNaxNBGL7vr3g7CpsQ2U17EWqaS1bQerDBDxANdpOdZKfO7oTdqaHKSvBQ8ObVIpIKlUiKLZRIRWthxp4Ki79h/0h8p60V5zT7PO/zMe@K1G8zOpupr2o7nxbDD66rtn8f6X29pfcN5NlqVx03ma0@nhxlTn5w8nPNvqom6nOqd7Ls9P2vTf1jIZ8ajZp46GAGi@FIHVwxSFOP2EZ@eLqpJ2qceWpPv0ufeQFTX/RYT560lvX0jvqOvrbT3AheZZgYMP1W7zWZ3ss829E7xZsRyw9WPTV@yno2TbPl1rJ3uxhu5VObYMdv@WHxercYfiL6mGSri7MZIcR14RblXMBAJDy4Bu11CalM/LhHkznLQnqxbFkdEacSIliC6wvVatWpVsGFebxZz/0EQsTvyYTFPaebiKgR@klDBLQUlS0ATs8MkcQpch4zRwCNH/p8nYIU0EdWWmCBMeNWVyRQMjKGinnMwnMDP2oXPg6ncU@GCFUqZXhpOmLfQERGz/w2PzOVYSIGILpdSEVEgfsvNv7xAZW0I5mIrXPlXwL7mmOeKzh1uOiVzjMfs1bZdF4xVYH6nRDNsL4RcKgsweWYlVmXz73om/Y5kyVCys6aYHGJ1NpJneBuzN64I8WDfp8mDT@lJVx1IDrrEY2lM0iYpDg8591t3H@0chNCGfF6jdUJVCD8X4YIMcUNdZGOSM3F4TL@5D8)

**Explanation:**

```python
¶¡                         # Split the (implicit) multi-line input-string on newlines
  ε                        # Map over each line:
   „//¡                    #  Split it on "//"
       н                   #  Only keep the first value of each list
        ðÚ                 #  Trim any leading/trailing spaces
   ð¡                      #  Then split it by spaces
                           #  (note: builtin `#` fails for lines that are lacking spaces)
     ε                     #  Map over each space-splitted substring:
      D                    #   Duplicate the current substring
       '¬¿Qi   }          '#   If it's equal to dictionary string "const"
            '¢Ž           '#    Push dictionary string "var" instead
      .γ        }          #   Then adjacent group-by the characters of the substring:
        žj                 #    Push builtin string "abc...xyzABC...XYZ012...789_"
          '$«             '#    Append "$"
             ©             #    Store this in variable `®` (without popping)
              s            #    Swap so the current character is at the top
               å           #    Check if this character is in this string
     }                     #  Close the inner map
   ˜                       #  Flatten it to a single list of strings
    Ć                      #  Enclose; append its own head (which we'll discard later)
     ü2                    #  Pop and push its overlapping pairs
       ε                   #  Map over each overlapping pair:
        н                  #   Pop and push the first item of the pair
         ð«                #   Append a space
           D               #   Duplicate it
        „¢Ž†³              #   Push dictionary string "var let"
             #             #   Split it on the space: ["var","let"]
              ð«           #   Append a space to each: ["var ","let "]
                Qài        #   If either is equal to the earlier pushed string:
                   yθ      #    Push the last item of the pair
                     ˆ     #    Pop and add it to the global array
                  ë        #   Else:
                   ¨       #    Remove the appended space again
                  }        #   Close the if-statement
        D                  #   Duplicate the string
         ¯                 #   Push the global array
          Ù                #   Uniquify it
           s               #   Swap so the copy of the string is at the top
            k              #   Get the index of this string in the global array
                           #   (or -1 if it's not in it)
             D             #   Duplicate this index
              di           #   If it's non-negative:
                ®          #    Push variable `®` ("a-zA-Z0-9_$")
                 è         #    Index the index into this string
               ë           #   Else:
                \          #    Discard the index from the stack
  ]                        # Close the open if-else and nested maps
   J                       # Join each inner list back together to a line
    õK                     # Remove any empty lines
      »                    # Join it back by newlines
.γ                         # Adjacent group-by characters again:
  '.Q                     '#  Check if it's equal to a "."
     yd                    #  Check if it's a digit
       ~                   #  OR to check if either of these two is truthy
 }ε                        # After the adjacent group-by: map over the substrings:
   D                       #  Duplicate the current substring
    di                     #  Pop the copy, and if it's an integer:
      Ð                    #   Triplicate it
       ï                   #   Pop one copy, and cast it to an integer
        Qi                 #   Pop the top two, and if their values are the same:
          ï                #    Cast it to an integer 
         }D                #   After this if, duplicate the result
           '.å≠i          '#   Pop the copy, and if it does NOT contain a ".":
                γ          #    Group to adjacent equal digits
                 `         #    Pop and push the groups to the stack
                  D        #    Duplicate the last one
                   ¨       #    Remove one of its digits
                    _i     #    If it's 0 (including "00"; "000"; etc.):
                      g    #     Pop and push its length
                       'e '#     Push an "e"
                         s #     Swap the length and "e" on the stack
                     }J    #    After the if-statement: join the stack back together
  ]                        # Close the still open if-statements and map
   J                       # Join everything back together
    D                      # Duplicate the string
     I‚                    # Pair the copy with the input-string
       ε                   # Map over this pair of multi-line strings:
        '"¡               '#  Split it on '"'
           ι               #  Uninterleave it into two parts
            θ              #  Pop and keep the last part
             €             #  Map over each string in this list:
              …"ÿ"         #  Surround it with leading/trailing '"'
       }`                  # After the map: push both lists of strings to the stack
         :                 # Replace them, to fix spaces within double-quotes
                           # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `'¬¿` is `"const"`; `'¢Ž` is `"var"`; and `„¢Ž†³` is `"var let"`.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://python.org), 501 <s>483 488 492</s> bytes

```python
import re
def G(m):b=m.group;return b(1)+f'e{H(b(2))}'+b(3)
E='\n'
I='\\g<1>'
H=len
C='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
C=[*C,*C.upper(),*'_$']
def S(A):
 s=lambda p,r='':re.sub('(?m)'+p,r,A);A=s('const ','var ');V=re.findall('(?m)(?:let|var) (\w+)\s',A);V.sort(key=H)
 for D in V:A=s(D,C.pop())if~-H(D)else C.remove(D)or A
 A=s('//.*| *$');A=s('^ *');A=s(' ?([=+*\\-\(\)<>/]+) ?',I);A=s(r'(?:\.0+)([^\d])',I);A=s('; +',';');F=A=s(r'(\d)(0+)([^\d])',G);A=s(E*2,E)
 while F!=A:F=A;A=s(E*2,E)
 print(A.strip())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVNdb9owFH33r7hElWwnqfnoQ6dAQCiw0qdV6oY0ETolYEhoEmdOUta13V9n18Cq1S@J7zn3nnPt6/K5TlRx9anUh5VaS9@yrHYbZjLLFOyVztYuxE0NVa2jYit1ixCEPU7IShVVDU2RmrQZ@HDd63Q6otOBNnTxjzxFGhKM39c6LbZio1UeJJEOkM6ue5wAZPJYGFGkWSe5lgUoMI@yRkKtoES0JkDAVNsVZKM0MJOXYkoX1XD1cTM4FxKZLLZ1giHH4fCCImYZryqTIlNbduIt0iU3QnemPsholaACapqEXQGOD@888kbeTZ5FqjJLa2ZZXOxUWjBrEOuhhR2ZdneFqNW3spQ6iCrJ8KTWatXksqjFXqe1RHZr8iX4@v1uCkmdZ8NBOrTAgeRjGkYsY91AZ3mMDNqpEcJLOqR5qXQNWpK13MANy7kX@7nYatWUfS3rRhcQsy53NlS@zFjMepy/USdmV5xMfRoWlNziJ9wOukNKZj4eHAl8GsUrrLdN0t1jlheq/Kmrunna/3r@TRFe2IFrB6IxPhl3bfrjgi6PBu7ZmHsEKj@L8ngdQelqn1JPS1E1MaNslHPqYNAd8/7Yrxg9zQ91qblZyvtzH7mbtFhHWXbis5GHN/2KOAcW7h0eVtSkz0WFnbNH@ezP8NDNSEwgLWDumcITNxClKhnn6ebP5YxNuMwqCYHQMldPEvfIHxM4mmi3hf0K9gU9m3oA@98vjNjCd@wwvAxZyAfD9hIHakTd2xOu0aIXio7D2eIhXC/5O0L74GBbfSz02T9TwzVn/1NvTtSp3XOn2MI@STMJn1v@2MOUD9DxAbCxMDNgmjrcM/Pg@OEv)

I somehow managed to half the number of bytes from when I first started shortening... never done that before
Anyway, I used a lot of regex to replace the strings properly. To test, just make the variable `A` contain the javascript code. Then, at the end, print `A`.

Changes: 
-4 bytes by using flag in pattern instead thanks to @Unmitigated
-5 bytes by inlining the for loop thanks to @Julian
+11 bytes to use standard I/O methods. Made this so much uglier and some fixes

Comment: It's shorter to set the multiline flag in the string itself: `re.sub('(?m)'+p,r,A)`

Comment: you can also inline the "for in if else" `for D in V:C.remove(D)if H(D)<2else s(D,C.pop())`?

Comment: Wow, I don't even know half of these Python characters! But I thought a high-level answer would use a lot of regexes ;)

Comment: Using a predefined input variable is not allowed under [default I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8731/110555). You would also need to include the print line in your main code body. I'm not sure of the OP's intent, but I suspect this needs to be a function, or at least a full program that takes input

Comment: Sorry about the late catch @12944querty, but could you add something to change `for ` into `for` and `while ` into `while`? Accidental miscommunication on my part.

Comment: In `var l`, when I change `l` to multichar name is not compressed.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg Fixed, thanks